# Vivado Higher Level Synthesis

Tags: c, vivado, synthesis

As far as Vivado how one can verify the design of lets say a general matrix multiplication scenario. If a target FPGA board is not available  then how one can compare speed comparison of computations of vivado with other softwares like Matlab for instance. How i can determine that c implementation is running faster than Matlab one??

Answer (score 1):

Vivado HLS provides the informations about throughput of and latency of the pipeline.
After you verify that the circuit can be synthesised to FPGA bitstream on specified frequency. You know the peak performance of the circuit.

Answer (score 0):

Well, one way is use a simulator like iSim or vsim, introduce artificial delays and run the simulation and see the timing.

Another way is to synthesise your design and evaluate the longest register to register path.

In case you have an asynchronous design, you'll need to use the timing method.